# How can I build a program using g++ with SCons, without depending on any external environmental variables?

Tags: g++, scons

I am trying to build a simple c++ hello world program using g++ with SCons. How can I specify that I want SCons to use g++ without any dependencies on external environment variables, such as PATH?

This is what I've tried:

```
env = Environment(CXX = 'C:/cygwin/bin/g++')
env.Program('helloworld.c++')
```

This is my result:

```
scons: warning: No version of Visual Studio compiler found - C/C++ 
compilers most likely not set correctly
File "C:\Python27\Scripts\scons.py", line 201, in <module>
C:/cygwin/bin/g++ /Fohelloworld.obj /c helloworld.c++ /TP /nologo
g++: error: /Fohelloworld.obj: No such file or directory
g++: error: /c: No such file or directory
g++: error: /TP: No such file or directory
g++: error: /nologo: No such file or directory
scons: *** [helloworld.obj] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer was [staring me straight in the face](https://scons.org/faq.html#Why_doesn.27t_SCons_find_my_compiler.2BAC8-linker.2BAC8-etc..3F_I_can_execute_it_just_fine_from_the_command_line.). My first problem was that the first part of this answer:

```
import os
env = Environment(ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']})
```

utilizes the OS PATH, which I explicitly wanted to avoid. My second problem was that I completely overlooked the answer below, which was the precise answer to my question:

> The way to guarantee that the build is repeatable is to explicitly
>   initialize the PATH

```
path= ['/bin', '/usr/bin', '/path/to/other/compiler/bin']
env = Environment(ENV = {'PATH' : path})
```

The reason I didn't realize this was the solution is because I simply misunderstood that `env['ENV']['PATH']` and `os.environ['PATH']` are completely separate and distinct. Whereas `os.environ['PATH']` is obviously the *external* OS PATH, `env['ENV']['PATH']` seems to be *SCons' internal equivalent*. You can set is to be whatever you please.

In the end, the precise solution I chose, and the one most readable to me was:

```
PATH = {'PATH' : ['C:/cygwin/bin']}
env = Environment(ENV = PATH)
env['ENV'] = PATH
env['CXX'] = 'g++'
env.Program('helloworld.c++')
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly cleaner way

```
env = Environment(tools=['g++','gnulink'])
env['ENV']['PATH'] = ['C:/cygwin/bin']
env['CXX'] = 'g++'
env.Program('helloworld.c++')
```

Another way:

```
env = Environment(tools=['g++','gnulink'])
env.PrependENVPath('PATH','C:/cygwin/bin')
env.Program('helloworld.c++')
```

Comment: Neither of these solutions work for me.

Solution 1 gives:

`File "C:\Python27\Scripts\scons.py", line 201, in <module>
g++ /Fohelloworld.obj /c helloworld.cxx /TP /nologo
g++: error: /Fohelloworld.obj: No such file or directory
g++: error: /c: No such file or directory
g++: error: /TP: No such file or directory
g++: error: /nologo: No such file or directory`

Solution 2 gives:

`File "C:\Python27\Scripts\scons.py", line 201, in <module>
g++ -o helloworld.o -c helloworld.cxx
'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: For solution 2 for your install change cygwin64 to cygwin. It works in my cygwin install which is 64 bit.  I'll update the above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`env = Environment(tools=['ar', 'cc', 'clang', 'clangxx', 'gcc', 'g++', 'gnulink', 'link'], ENV=os.environ, toolpath=['custom_path'])`.

The command above will:

1. Create a variable ***env*** of type Environment.
2. Tells scons to set up requires tools.
3. Find these tools in system variable.
4. Else find in custom path(you can omit the last parameter: **toolpath=['custom_path']** if you don't need it).

Where:

- **ar**: Sets construction variables for the ar library archiver.

Sets: $AR, $ARCOM, $ARFLAGS, $LIBPREFIX, $LIBSUFFIX, $RANLIB, $RANLIBCOM, $RANLIBFLAGS.

- **cc**: Sets construction variables for generic POSIX C compilers.

Sets: $CC,  $CCCOM,  $CCFLAGS,  $CFILESUFFIX,  $CFLAGS,  $CPPDEFPREFIX,  $CPPDEFSUFFIX,$FRAMEWORKPATH,  $FRAMEWORKS,  $INCPREFIX,  $INCSUFFIX,  $SHCC,  $SHCCCOM,  $SHCCFLAGS,$SHCFLAGS, $SHOBJSUFFIX.

**clang**: Set construction variables for the Clang C compiler.

Sets: $CC, $CCVERSION, $SHCCFLAGS.

**clangxx**: Set construction variables for the Clang C++ compiler.

Sets: $CXX, $CXXVERSION, $SHCXXFLAGS, $SHOBJSUFFIX,$STATIC_AND_SHARED_OBJECTS_ARE_THE_SAME.

**g++**: Set construction variables for the gXX C++ compiler.

Sets: $CXX, $CXXVERSION, $SHCXXFLAGS, $SHOBJSUFFIX.

**gcc**: Set construction variables for the gcc C compiler.

Sets: $CC, $CCVERSION, $SHCCFLAGS.

**gnulink**: Set construction variables for GNU linker/loader

Sets:    $LDMODULEVERSIONFLAGS,    $RPATHPREFIX,    $RPATHSUFFIX,    $SHLIBVERSIONFLAGS,$SHLINKFLAGS, $_LDMODULESONAME, $_SHLIBSONAME.

**link**: Sets construction variables for generic POSIX linkers. This is a "smart" linker tool which selects a compiler tocomplete the linking based on the types of source files.

Sets: $LDMODULE, $LDMODULECOM, $LDMODULEFLAGS, $LDMODULENOVERSIONSYMLINKS,$LDMODULEPREFIX, $LDMODULESUFFIX, $LDMODULEVERSION, $LDMODULEVERSIONFLAGS,$LIBDIRPREFIX, $LIBDIRSUFFIX, $LIBLINKPREFIX, $LIBLINKSUFFIX, $LINK,$LINKCOM, $LINKFLAGS, $SHLIBSUFFIX, $SHLINK, $SHLINKCOM, $SHLINKFLAGS,$__LDMODULEVERSIONFLAGS, $__SHLIBVERSIONFLAGS.Uses: $LDMODULECOMSTR, $LINKCOMSTR, $SHLINKCOMSTR

Or you can use default config tools for your system by:

`env = Environment(tools=['default'], ENV=os.environ)`

To quote from scons man 4.1.0

default

> Sets construction variables for a default list of Tool modules. Use
> default in the tools list to retain the original defaults,  since  the
> tools  parameter  is  treated  as  a  literal  statement  of  the
> tools  to  be  made  available  in  that construction environment, not
> an addition.

> The list of tools selected by default is not static, but
> is dependent both on the platform and on the software installed on the
> platform. Some tools will not initialize if an underlying command is
> not found, and some tools are selected from  a  list  of  choices  on
> a  first-found  basis.  The  finished  tool  list  can  be  examined
> by  inspecting  the  TOOLS construction variable in the construction
> environment.

> On all platforms, all tools from the following list are
> selected whose respective conditions are met: filesystem,wix, lex,
> yacc, rpcgen, swig, jar, javac, javah, rmic, dvipdf, dvips, gs, tex,
> latex, pdflatex, pdftex, tar, zip, textfile.

> On Linux systems, the
> default tools list selects (first-found): a C compiler from gcc,
> intelc, icc, cc; a C++ compilerfrom g++, intelc, icc, cxx; an
> assembler from gas, nasm, masm; a linker from gnulink, ilink; a
> Fortran compilerfrom gfortran, g77, ifort, ifl, f95, f90, f77; and a
> static archiver 'ar'. It also selects all found from the list m4,
> rpm.

> On  Windows  systems,  the  default  tools  list  selects
> (first-found):  a  C  compiler  from  msvc,  mingw,  gcc,  intelc,icl,
> icc, cc, bcc32; a C++ compiler from msvc, intelc, icc, g++, cxx,
> bcc32; an assembler from masm, nasm, gas,386asm; a linker from mslink,
> gnulink, ilink, linkloc, ilink32; a Fortran compiler from gfortran,
> g77, ifl, cvf, f95,f90, fortran; and a static archiver from mslib, ar,
> tlib; It also selects all found from the list msvs, midl.

> On MacOS
> systems, the default tools list selects (first-found): a C compiler
> from gcc, cc; a C++ compiler from g++, cxx; an assembler 'as'; a
> linker from applelink, gnulink; a Fortran compiler from gfortran, f95,
> f90, g77; anda static archiver ar. It also selects all found from the
> list m4, rpm.

> Default  lists  for  other  platforms  can  be  found  by
> examining  the  scons  source  code  (see  SCons/Tool/**init**.py).